# What response is required for captive portal to appear?

Tags: android, ios, http, captivenetwork, captiveportal

I am trying to implement captive portal on a small embedded device.

As I understand all I need is to capture smartphone requests to special urls and send response containing captive portal page. In order not to maintain list of all the possible URLs I have set up a DNS which resolves all the hosts to my device IP.

Now when I connect android device to my network, I catch a request to `/generate_204` and send redirect response. Here is an example of a request and response from curl command:

```
curl -v http://google.com/generate_204 

*   Trying 192.168.1.1...
* Connected to google.com (192.168.1.1) port 80 (#0)
> GET /generate_204 HTTP/1.1
> Host: google.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.47.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Found
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 0
< Location: /
< 
* Connection #0 to host google.com left intact
```

Using Postman/Chrome I am redirected to a 192.168.1.1/ and required page is loaded. However I tested 4 android devices and only one showed me a popup. Same problem with ios. I catched a request to `/hotspot-detect.html` returned the same response as above and nothing happened. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi- Any idea how to close the Custom captive page after authentication in Android? or how to force connectivity check from my custom captive page? I tried window.location redirect but sometimes its stuck with 200 response instead of 204. Have you ever faced this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer. Location header in redirect response must look differently. In particular:

```
Location: http://192.168.1.1/
```

This solves the issue.

Comment: @LavaSlider yes, all requests are redirected using DNS. However the problem is in the `Location` header format. It Must contain either a domain name or an IP address of the host where redirect points to. It is HTTP feature which has nothing to do with DNS redirects.

Answer (score 0):

It is my understanding that if you return anything other than what the captive specific portal test site returns (i.e., what http://google.com/generate_204 returns if that was the requested URI or what http://captive.apple.com//hotspot-detect.html returns if that was the requested URI) then what you return will be displayed, the so-called splash screen. Returning what these URLs return should suppress the splash screen and fool the device into thinking it is connected to the Internet.

Comment: Thabjs for your answer! I understand it exactly the same. As you can see from my post I send redirect response for /generate_204 request. However splash screen does not appear.

Comment: Right, **don't** send the redirect response for /generate_204. Just respond with a regular 200 status text or html page to have it appear as the splash screen.

Comment: I'll check that. However I always find that answer should contain redirect. Even Wiki says that: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal . See `Implementation` section.

Comment: I found a solution, you can look at my answer.